# AbstractJAXBProvider.getJAXBContext(..) method Peformance Issues

Tags: java, performance, jaxb

In my application JAXB is used for message parsing, it's a XML request/response based RESTFUL application.

I am observing performance issue with JAXB, this issue is inconsistent and was hard to reproduce.

However I was able to reproduce it in our Test environment during performance testing. I observed in Dynatrace that below JAXB method of AbstractJAXBProvider.java from cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.10-sources.jar is getting blocked for 1 to 2 seconds. It happened when 20 simultaneous requests came in, all 20 threads were blocked on this method for 1 to 2 seconds.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public JAXBContext getJAXBContext(Class<?> type, Type genericType) throws JAXBException {
    if (mc != null) {
        ContextResolver<JAXBContext> resolver = 
            mc.getResolver(ContextResolver.class, JAXBContext.class);
        if (resolver != null) {
            JAXBContext customContext = resolver.getContext(type);
            if (customContext != null) {
                return customContext;
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized (classContexts) {
        JAXBContext context = classContexts.get(type);
        if (context != null) {
            return context;
        }
    }

    JAXBContext context = getPackageContext(type, genericType);

    return context != null ? context : getClassContext(type, genericType);
}
```

Is there as way to avoid this bottleneck, so that under highly concurrent requests performance is not affected.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Got your PurePaths to share? Dynatrace should show you whether the blocking time is synchronization, wait, cpu or I/O. I assume it is synchronization in that sync block - but - 1-2s sounds a lot for such a short sync block. Could it be that the time is actually in a different method called by this one? The PurePath would show you data. If you want - share it through my http://bit.ly/sharepurepath program

Comment: I suspect the container you are running blocks new requests above 20 requests and puts them in a backlog. Can you make the same performance load test without this code ?

Comment: Andreas Grabner, I have confirmed in the PurePaths that the blocking time is due to synchronization. Below entries from purepaths confirm that the threads are blocking due to synchronization.                                                                     getJAXBContext(Class, Type) 2682.39 CPU Total: 7.601 ms, Sync Total: 2,674.792 ms, Wait Total: 0 ms, Suspension
Total: 0 ms
Abstract-
JAXBProvider
Java Web Services]

Comment: Andreas Grabner, If all threads are blocking on synchronized block of getJAXBContext(..) method then is there a way to resolved this issue under highly concurrent requests.